# Plsql case is not reading properly from case

Tags: plsql

I need to read data row by row and update it based on the matching case.

My code is just reading `ORBREFTND` and inserting  `Refund` from case , not reading other cases. What am i doing wrong.

```
DECLARE
    v_tot_rows   NUMBER (3);

    v_eval       ISG.SWR_CERT_TXN_MSG_TYPE.DESC_TX%TYPE;

    CURSOR pltfm_msg_type_cur
    IS
        SELECT sctmt.PLTFM_MSG_TYPE_CD
          FROM ISG.SWR_CERT_TXN_MSG_TYPE  sctmt
               JOIN ISG.FEATURE_VALUES ft_val
                   ON sctmt.SWR_CERT_FETR_VAL_ID = ft_val.FEATURE_VAL
               JOIN ISG.FEATURE_CATEGORY ft_cat
                   ON ft_val.FEATURE_CAT = ft_cat.FEATURE_CAT
         WHERE     ft_cat.SHORT_DESCRIP = 'PLT'
               AND ft_val.FEATURE_VALUE = 'Orbital';
BEGIN
    FOR msg_code IN pltfm_msg_type_cur
    LOOP
        CASE msg_code.PLTFM_MSG_TYPE_CD
            WHEN 'WAC'
            THEN
                v_eval := 'Authorization and Mark for Capture';
            WHEN 'ORBAUTHCAP'
            THEN
                v_eval := 'Authorization Capture';
            WHEN 'ORBREFTND'
            THEN
                v_eval := 'Refund';
        END CASE;

        UPDATE ISG.SWR_CERT_TXN_MSG_TYPE sctmt
           SET sctmt.DESC_TX = v_eval;
    END LOOP;

    COMMIT;

    v_tot_rows := SQL%ROWCOUNT;
    /* Implicit Attribute %ROWCOUNT is used   to find the number of rows affected     by the update command */
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('Total records updated : ' || v_tot_rows);
END;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a where-condition:

```
    UPDATE ISG.SWR_CERT_TXN_MSG_TYPE sctmt
       SET sctmt.DESC_TX = v_eval
     WHERE sctmt.primarykey = msg_code.primarykey; -- This one is missing. Don't know your primary key..
```

Without the `where` you'll always set the value of the last cursor-object to all objects in your table `ISG.SWR_CERT_TXN_MSG_TYPE`.

You also need to select the key from your table:

```
    CURSOR pltfm_msg_type_cur
    IS
        SELECT sctmt.PLTFM_MSG_TYPE_CD,
               sctmt.PRIMARYKEY -- select key here
          FROM ISG.SWR_CERT_TXN_MSG_TYPE  sctmt
               JOIN ISG.FEATURE_VALUES ft_val
                   ON sctmt.SWR_CERT_FETR_VAL_ID = ft_val.FEATURE_VAL
               JOIN ISG.FEATURE_CATEGORY ft_cat
                   ON ft_val.FEATURE_CAT = ft_cat.FEATURE_CAT
         WHERE     ft_cat.SHORT_DESCRIP = 'PLT'
               AND ft_val.FEATURE_VALUE = 'Orbital';
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Kara, you saved my day

Comment: You're welcome. A click on "accept answer" would be great ;)